# Should I build my gradle project using the Dockerfile

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle

I'm reading about dockerization of Spring Boot applications and all (or almost all) tutorials are based on some simple Dockerfile like

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

It usually work (however you may need to change some build target paths) but as far as I understand **it requires us to build the application jar before the `docker build` command will be run**.

I'm actually working with Gradle but for the Maven, I guess, it looks the same.

My question is: is it good convention?

If I'll download some repostitory and run `docker build`, regardless having proper Dockerfile, it will fail because there is no `target/*.jar` file (at least if someone did not commit the `/build` directory :P).

Should we then include some `./gradlew build` commands in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Why? `target` is for maven for Gradle use `build/libs` instead of `target`.

Comment: Yeah I know - as I said, you need to change the directory for Gradle. But it doesn't matter - the question is about should I have the build Maven/Gradle command in the Dockerfile

Comment: You can make a multi stage maven build, but if you should depends. And as such I'm going to mark this question as opinion based.

Comment: Yeah it may be opinion based. Anyway thanks a lot for mentioning multi stage build. It may be an answer

Comment: Both approaches are fine.  I'd guess that building the jar file outside Docker became an engrained pattern before there were multi-stage builds.

Comment: Have you read over: https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/creating-efficient-docker-images-with-spring-boot-2-3

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker
you should use this project

or
`jar_path=$(find . |grep $APP_NAME|grep jar|grep -v original|grep -v repository|grep -v templates)`

`mv $jar_path ./app.jar`

Comment: Thanks but it does not answer my question. I want to build the docker image using just `docker` command and I'm asking how to create properly Dockerfile